# Including GLAD into a project, when compiling get "unresolved external symbol gladLoadGLLoader"

Tags: c++, opengl, unresolved-external

I'm working with OpenGL and trying to include GLAD into my project, however I'm unsure where to link the glad.c

I'm getting the error

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol gladLoadGLLoader referenced in function "public: __cdecl zelmEngineCore::zelmEngineCore(void)" (??0zelmEngineCore@@QEAA@XZ) OpenGLGLFWTestApp
```

My dependencies file is as so

```
#pragma once

#ifdef _WIN64
    #include <Windows.h>
#endif

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <glad\glad.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
```

I'm calling -

```
gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress;
```

From the constructor of zelmEngineCore.

Here the constructor

```
#include "zelmDependencies.h"
#include "zelmEngineWindow.h"

zelmEngineCore::zelmEngineCore()
{
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        std::cout << "Error: Couldn't initalise glfw!";
    }

    //Set error callback function
    //glfwSetErrorCallback(zelmEngineCore::glfwErrorCallback);

    //Before creation of the window, you can set the minimum OpenGL
    //version, but we're not using openGL, so it not needed
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);

    gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress); //Causing the unresolved exteral symbol
}

zelmEngineCore::~zelmEngineCore()
{
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

My zelmEngineCore class is as follows -

```
#pragma once

#include "zelmDependencies.h"
#include "zelmEngineWindow.h"

class zelmEngineCore
{
private:

protected:

public:
    zelmEngineCore();
    ~zelmEngineCore();
};
```

And here main.cpp

```
#include "zelmEngine\zelmEngineCore.h"

int main()
{
    zelmEngineCore engine;

    return 0;
}
```

This my C/C++ / General additional directories includes, I impression I haven't included glad.c file properly. I tried including it in the Linker, but I also get impression Linker is used for .lib(s) includes.
[image: C/C++ / General]

Comment: Have you got glad.c within scope of the project, i.e. in the solution explorer?

Comment: Nope, I'll try that now!

Comment: @platinum95 Such a simple mistake, so much wasted time! I tried that earlier, but I don't think the files were included properly. Thank you!

Comment: No problem at all, we've all been there!